# awk all lines in the input file whose last field contains at least one uppercase

Tags: awk, capslock

I'm having some real time with a home assignment here. As a due diligence I was browsing web for the last 2.30 hours and reading awk tutorial to find the solution, hopeless. 
Here is the line that I came up with:

awk '/[A-Z]/ {print $NF}' < tweedle.txt     (Tweedle.txt is a poem)

**current output:**

```
Tweedledee
Tweedledee
battle;
Tweedledee
rattle.
crow,
tar-barrel;
so,
quarrel.
```

**expected output**    -last fields that start with upper case

```
Tweedledee
Tweedledee
Tweedledee
```

just prints the last fields with both upper and lower case.

Need your expertise guys. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please consider editing your question to include sample input, expected output, and your current output. Half of getting a useful solution is being able to supply a meaningful definition of the problem ;-).. Good luck!

Comment: Any other ideas guys? commands specified by Faiz , thx to him btw, are not working properly

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
awk '$NF ~ /[A-Z]/' < tweedle.txt
```

This reads: accept all lines whose `NF`<sup>th</sup> field matches the regex `/[A-Z]/`. Awk's default action is to just print the line, and that is what I am assuming you want to do.

And if you want to print just the last field (your question does not make this very clear) of all lines whose last field contains at least one uppercase,

```
awk '$NF ~ /[A-Z]/ {print $NF}' < tweedle.txt
```

By the way, here's how I tested this:

```
faiz@strange-love:/tmp$ cat tweedle.txt 
a b aBoo
c D
a x y
G
j h g
faiz@strange-love:/tmp$ awk '$NF ~ /[A-Z]/ {print $NF}'  tweedle.txt 
aBoo
D
G
faiz@strange-love:/tmp$ awk '$NF ~ /[A-Z]/'  tweedle.txt 
a b aBoo
c D
G
```

Providing something like this would really give us a far better understanding of your problem.

Comment: [root@serg1a ~]# awk '$NF ~/[A-Z]/' < tweedle.txt 
Tweedledum and Tweedledee
Tweedledum and Tweedledee
Agreed to have a battle;
For Tweedledum said Tweedledee
Had spoiled his nice new rattle.
Just then flew down a monstrous crow,
As black as a tar-barrel;
Which frightened both the heroes so,
They quite forgot their quarrel.   - prints out all lines within the file

Comment: I am sorry, but you'll need to be more clear. What really is your problem, and could you edit your question to better describe you input, output and the exact commands you are running. Use the wiki formatting to make your question as clear as possible.

Comment: The second command print outs  all last fields disregarding the upper case condition:[root@serg1a ~]# awk '$NF ~ /[A-Z]/ {print $NF}' < tweedle.txt
Tweedledee
Tweedledee
battle;
Tweedledee
rattle.
crow,
tar-barrel;
so,
quarrel.

Comment: I don't see any reason it shouldn't work. I've updated my answer showing how it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
 awk '$NF ~ /^[A-Z]/{print $NF}' tweedle.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your input file there are many possible solutions:

```
awk '$NF~/^[A-Z]/ && $0=$NF' file
```

or (from your "current output", this line works too):

```
awk '/[a-z]$/' file
```